# Insert Base64 image to pdf using pyfpdf

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm using pyfpdf in python to generate pdf files. I have a Base64 which I want to insert into a pdf file without having to save it as an image in my file system. But the pyfpdf image function only accepts file path.

```
fpdf.image(name, x = None, y = None, w = 0, h = 0, type = '', link = '')
```

Is there a way (hack) to directly insert base64 or buffered image from memory, without having to save into the file system beforehand? I even checked their source code on github and couldn't figure.

link : https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/tree/master/fpdf

Comment: you can subclass `fpdf` and override `load_resource` to return `BytesIO` file-like objects.

Comment: That's a great Idea. It'd help me if you could post your detailed answer if i'm stuck.

Comment: All the image parsing code calls `load_resource`, go take a look at it and ask a specific question if there's something that's unclear. Alternatively, you might want to explore using a different pdf library since this one looks like an unholy mess (it's a PHP port)

Comment: I also felt that something was off with this library but it's really easy. Do you think this works in a pure python environment or do I need to install any php dependencies ? I would like to why being 'PHP port' is an issue here. I'm in the early stage of project, so your views on it will really help.

Comment: I don't know, it looks like pure python from what little I've seen. By 'PHP port' I mean someone took some PHP code and converted it to python. It doesn't seem like it's been maintained for some time. On the other hand, if it works and does what you want, more power to you. You might want to test it with images off the filesystem, if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pvg mentioned in the comments, overriding load_resource function with your base64 functionality does the trick.

```
import base64,io

def load_resource(self, reason, filename):
    if reason == "image":
        if filename.startswith("http://") or filename.startswith("https://"):
            f = BytesIO(urlopen(filename).read())
        elif filename.startswith("data"):
            f = filename.split('base64,')[1]
            f = base64.b64decode(f)
            f = io.BytesIO(f)
        else:
            f = open(filename, "rb")
        return f
    else:
        self.error("Unknown resource loading reason \"%s\"" % reason)
```

EDIT :

This is a sample code to insert images into pdf. I commented some instructions in code.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import os
import io
import base64


class PDF(FPDF):

    def load_resource(self, reason, filename):
        if reason == "image":
            if filename.startswith("http://") or filename.startswith("https://"):
                f = BytesIO(urlopen(filename).read())
            elif filename.startswith("data"):
                f = filename.split('base64,')[1]
                f = base64.b64decode(f)
                f = io.BytesIO(f)
            else:
                f = open(filename, "rb")
            return f
        else:
            self.error("Unknown resource loading reason \"%s\"" % reason)


    def sample_pdf(self,img,path):

        self.image(img,h=70,w=150,x=30,y=100,type="jpg")
        #make sure you use appropriate image format here jpg/png
        pdf.output(path, 'F')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = # pass your base64 image
    # you can find sample base64 here : https://pastebin.com/CaZJ7n6s

    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf_path = # give path to where you want to save pdf
    pdf.sample_pdf(img,pdf_path)
```

Comment: In your `if filename.startswith("http://") or filename.startswith("https://"):` block, you need to change `f = BytesIO(.....)...` to `f = io.BytesIO(.....)...)`. Also I am uncertain as to what library `urlopen(...)` belongs to. My IDE is showing that it can't determine that either. A revision in this would be great. Thank you much.

Comment: To anyone else finding this issue. This approach only works on the development version fpdf. the release on pypi (1.7.2) at time of writing handles loading images differently. To make this answer work with the version on pypi, you need to override FPDF._parsepng/jpg with the code from the master branch on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing this issue lately and the answer from Uchiha Madara didn't work in my case, so I fixed it in a slightly different way. When I tried it with Uchiha's Method, I the same FileNotFound Error you do if you supply an image without any modification to your code ( without the load_resource function ). Since I really needed a solution and there was no way around, I looked into the module code which can be found in

C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py

If you look around there for a bit, you notice that the image is imported via the _parsepng function. So, we need to edit this to accept a base64 data string.

Basically, what you need to do to fix it:

In the function, you need to add an elif at the top to check whether the "filename" contains a string indicating it's base64, and you need to import 2 new modules.

Copy & paste this code below the first if-Statement to check for a URL:

```
elif "data:image/png;base64" in name:
                f = name.split('base64,')[1]
                f = base64.b64decode(f)
                f = io.BytesIO(f)
```

This just looks for the string which is typical for every base64-encoded image, and if it's there and decodes it.

You need to import the base64 and the io modules at the top of the script, so just do that via

```
import base64, io
```

Now just supply your base64 string as the file path like you would do normally, and it should work ( did on my tests with python 3.8 ).

Contact me if you have any questions, I hope I can help some people reading this in the future.