# load_resource function not found as a class method of FPDF

Tags: python, fpdf, class-attributes

I am looking at the answer to the following question: [Insert Base64 image to pdf using pyfpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195075/insert-base64-image-to-pdf-using-pyfpdf)

The answer suggested here was to override the existing `load_resource` method.

What I did instead was

```
class EnhancedPdf(FPDF):

    def load_resource(self, reason, filename):
        if reason == "image":
            if filename.startswith("data"):
                f = filename.split("base64,")[1]
                f = base64.b64decode(f)
                f = BytesIO(f)
                return f
            else:
                return super().load_resource(reason, filename)
```

However, Pycharm highlights the super call with the message "Unresolved attribute reference "load_resource" for class "FPDF"

In my command line, I ran the commands

```
from fpdf import FPDF
   dir(FPDF)
```

Inspecting this list, I see `load_resource` function is indeed not a listed method. Hence my question is why is the `load_resource` function not visible?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different version of pyfpdf where load_resource() is not present anymore.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3 ?

Comment: in the latest version its definitely there `def load_resource(self, reason, filename)` on line 1774

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I think I am using the latest version. I installed a few days ago using pip. version number 1.7.2

Comment: The "latest" version on pypi is from 2015! Use fpdf2 - it's a fork that has been updated to support python 3.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle which python file? fpdf.py?

Comment: @Cucu how do i install this via conda or pip? pip install fpdf2?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/  
You can simply do a 'pip install fpdf2'

Comment: @Cucu what should the import statement be? ```from fpdf2 import FPDF``` returned a No Module named "fpdf2" error

Comment: Nope, use 'from fpdf import FPDF'

Comment: @Cucu do i need to uninstall the old fpdf package?

Comment: Remember to remove the old fpdf, so that you don't have conflicts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205423/discussion-between-cucu-and-lost1).

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I now see load_resource as a function in image_parsing.py - not a class method on the FPDF class (in fpdf.py) having updated to fpdf2.

Comment: it still bothers me that it cannot be seen as a class method in fdpf 1.7.2 cause in the source its there.

Comment: it seems the 1.7.2 installed via pip isnt the same as the github version of 1.7.2 and indeed `load_resource` is not a method in FPDF class. I loaded the module via pip and then debugged in pycharm

Comment: its good you haev switched to fpdf2 like @Cucu suggested as this is a great example of how using a module thats no been maintained in a while can cause issues between the documentation and what it acutally is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are using Python 3.x where x >= 5 .

On the pypi it says that the module has only experimental support for python 3.y where y <= 4 .

Try it with python 2.7 and it might work.

PS: Better try https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/, the updated version. For bugs or issues see https://github.com/alexanderankin/pyfpdf .

If you really want to use the old version, you can install whatever version you want from the original repo like this

```
pip install git+https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf@<branchname of tag or commit>
```